# Java How to tell which Object is in a HashMap

Tags: java, object, inheritance, casting, hashmap

I have a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, anObjectClass> myHash = new HashMap<String, anObjectClass>();
```

I have my `anObjectClass`:

```
public class anObjectClass {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> myObjectList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I have another class that extends my `anObjectClass` that adds another String:

```
public class secondObjectClass extends anObjectClass {
String quote;
}
```

Which means I have two kinds of objects within my HashMap:

1. My `anObjectClass` objects which have a `String name` and an `ArrayList` of `Strings`: `myObjectList`
2. And my `secondObjectClass` objects which adds another `String`: `quote`.

My question is, if I have a String key, say "ABC". I know I can tell whether or not there is a key "ABC" in my HashMap with the `containsKey()` method. But once I have found a key "ABC", how do I tell if it is an `anObjectClass` object or a `secondObjectClass` object? In other words, how can I tell what kind of object matches with that key? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get the value and check using `instanceof`.

Comment: hint: if you need to use instanceof (correct answer to your question) - your design is wrong

Comment: @Andreas Thank you! What do you mean Lashane?

Comment: I mean what I wrote - your design is wrong, you need to re-think your application architecture

Comment: @Lashane How is that supposed to help me? That's like telling someone to start over and not telling them why lol

Comment: Won't instanceof return true if object is of class secondObjectClass and is compared against its superclass? (If order of if else is messed up)

Comment: Can you share some more details so that we can give better suggestions: how are you using the map, i.e. what does your client code (the code that calls `myHash.containsKey()` etc.) look like?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Hi Mick. My code is large enough that I would have to explain a lot. Everyone else kindly answered my question, unlike Lashane. Everyone else was helpful! Thanks for asking though!

Comment: You should be exploiting polymorphism so that you don't care about the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword `instanceof` to determine the types of different objects in Java.

In your example, say you are trying to determine the type of an object `obj` that is either an instance of `anObjectClass` or `secondObjectClass`. You can tell the type by using the following code:

```
if(obj instanceof secondObjectClass) {
    // obj is of type secondObjectClass
} else if(obj instanceof anObjectClass) {
    // obj is of type anObjectClass
}
```

This is fine, but beware - types are *transitive*. That is, an instance of `secondObjectClass` is also of type `anObjectClass` because it is a subclass of it. It is therefore helpful to be as specific as possible when using `instanceof`.

Comment: Gotcha, so making sure I am doing it in the right order is important. If you had switched the order of what you wrote, and kept the else if, I would get a true value for instanceof anObjectClass, even though it might be a secondObjectClass. Which would be correct but not what I want. Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that using `ìnstanceof` is generally a [symptom of bad design](http://wiki.c2.com/?InstanceofInConditionals) and it can pretty much always be avoided.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks I think it will do the job for my program (I hope so!). But I will try to avoid it in the future, kinda crunched for time atm.

Answer (score 2):

For objects for which you control the definitions, define a boolean

```
  boolean isBaseClass() { return(true); }
and in the subclass define
  boolean isBaseClass() { return(false): }
```

but more generally, use method inheritance instead of this kind of test,
because it can be extended to any family of classes.

// bad

```
if(x.isBaseClass()) { doThis(); } else { doThat(); }
```

// better

```
x.doNextThing()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `isAssignableFrom` method of `Class` class.

So your code will look like

```
if(obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(BaseClass.class)) {
    //bla
}

if(obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(SuperClass.class)) {
    //blabla
}
```

I like this because I don't have to worry about the order of if else's nor do I need to write nested if elses.

**EDIT**

By order I meant while using instanceof, your if elses have to be placed in a way that the sub class is checked before the base class instanceof check. Sorry for causing any confusion. Thanks @EJP for pointing out.

Comment: Doesn't compile. You can't call a method of `Class` via an object. And you do have to worry about the order. `BaseClass.class.isAssignableFrom(SuperClass.class)` is true.

Comment: Your comment about order is still wrong. The same considerations apply to both `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom()`, as I have already stated. NB I was the downvioter and I **did** point out your mistakes.

Comment: @EJP you are still not getting it. I know the order inside if(//here) matters. I was talking about the issue with instanceof which is not there with isAssiganbleFrom because of fact that the types are transitive.